# EF Core 6 - how to define a relationship that doesn't use a primary key

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have 3 classes and am using EF Core 6 to create a database with 3 corresponding tables:

```
public class Device
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public Guid DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}

public class Procedure
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public Guid DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceType
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Procedure> Procedures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeviceType> DeviceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The `DeviceType` class is in a third party library and I am unable to change it or add any properties to it.

I would like to add a `Procedures` property to my `Device` class that returns all procedures that have the same `DeviceTypeID` as the device.

It would look like this:

```
public class Device
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public Guid DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    
    // gets all procedures with matching DeviceTypeID
    public virtual ICollection<Procedure> Procedures { get; set; }
}
```

How can I configure the model for this relationship so that I can do the following?

```
public Procedure GetFirstProcedureForDevice(MyDbContext dbContext, Guid deviceId)
{
    var device = dbContext.Devices
                          .Include(m => m.Procedures)
                          .First(m => m.ID == deviceId);
        
    var procedure = device.Procedures.FirstOrDefault();
    
    return procedure;
}
```

I have tried to configure the `Device.Procedures` property in `MyDbContext.OnModelCreating` to define a relationship that can do this but have not been successful.

Comment: Well, unless you have some unconventional stuff in the database (e.g. the names of your classes don't match the names of the tables inside the database) your code should already work as-is. EF is smart enough to recognize and map navigation properties automatically. Have you tried it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev I'm not doing anything unconventional as far as I'm aware. When I create a database migration using this code, the generated migration adds a DeviceID column to the Procedures table and a foreign key between the Procedures and Devices tables. Presumably this is done because EF is trying to create a direct relationship between devices and procedures, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Oh, now I get it, I didn't read your task correctly at the first time. Then you'll likely need to implement this functionality yourself, EF won't calculate this kind of relationship for you. Let me add an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

EF likely won't be able to establish this kind of relationship automatically, since `DeviceTypeID` is not a primary key in either table. You can try something like this to tell EF how to establish the relation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
    .HasMany(device => device.Procedures)
    .WithOne(procedure => procedure.Device) // You will have to add Device property to the Procedure class
    .HasPrincipalKey(device => new { device.DeviceTypeID })
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

This, however, might not work due to the fact that `DeviceTypeID` is not a primary key. If this won't work, you'll have to resort to directly querying your Procedures like this:

```
public Procedure GetFirstProcedureForDevice(MyDbContext dbContext, Guid deviceId)
{
    var device = dbContext.Devices
        .First(m => m.ID == deviceId);
        
    var procedure = dbContext.Procedures
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeviceTypeId == device.DeviceTypeID);
    
    return procedure;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need a many-to-many relationship, then EF currently only supports such a relationship via a join table. In your case, you might consider this structure then:

```
public class Device
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public Guid DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Procedure> Procedures { get; set; }
}

public class Procedure
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public Guid DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

In this case EF should theoretically recognize a many-to-many relationship and (as long as you follow code-first approach with migrations) automatically create a join table that would be called something like `DeviceProcedure` that will be used to link the entities together. Afterwards you'd be welcome to use it in the way you originally described in your question.

If you do not use code-first, you will have to add a join entity explicitly, like this:

```
public class DeviceProcedure
{
    public Guid DeviceID { get; set; }
    public Guid ProcedureID { get; set; }
}
```

and corresponding table. EF is smart enough to go from there.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Unfortunately adding a Device property to the Procedure class will tie the procedure to a single device. Let's say there is a "mobile phone" device type and I have many mobile phones (devices) in my database. There could be a procedure called "screen repair" for the "mobile phone" device type, which would be applicable to many devices. The procedure-to-device relationship I'm looking for would be many-to-many using the DeviceTypeId as a common field. As you say, I may have to resort to querying which could be done with a join relatively easily.

Comment: @BenHarden Well, if you need a many-to-many there then EF basically force you to use a join table (explicitly or implicitly). You might be interested in [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1368) and the issues referenced from there.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly